# ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate()

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, concurrentdictionary

I am trying to use the AddOrUpdate() method in the ConcurrentDictionary class. I am having trouble
with the Update peice. The following is the code:

```
dictionary.AddOrUpdate(oid, pList, (o,p) =>
{
    for (int i=0; i < p.Count; i++)
        p[i] = pList[i];
    return p;
});
```

I would like to update the 3 values contained in a pList object when/if
I hit the dictionary with a key that is already present. At the moment,
only the very last for iteration ( p[2]) is being updated in the dictionary.
What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds similar to this issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx does it work ok if you just return pList or create a a new list and return that?

Comment: exact same behavior, only the last item in the list gets updated. The other 2 stay the same.

Comment: I found an error in the code generating plist. All I needed was (o,p)=>pList